# {$a..3} does not expand right in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Why the output is `{1..3}` rather than `123` ?

```
#!/bin/sh

a=1
for i in {$a..3}
do
    echo -n $i
done
```

If I change `{$a..3}` to `$(echo {$a..3})`, it does not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brace expansion is performed before parameter substitution. But since that isn't a valid brace expansion, it isn't expanded. Use `seq` instead.

Comment: It doesn't. You only think it does.

Comment: Or your shell isn't `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

[Ignacio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18680630/2698019) is right.
Here are some other solutions!

You can use a [c-style for-loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for) in `bash`:

```
for (( i=a; i<=3; i++ ))
```

Or you can use dangerous `eval`, but you have to be sure that `$a` variable can't be anything else but a number, especially if the user is able to change it:

```
for i in $(echo eval {$a..3})
```

Or `while` loop with a variable in pure `sh`:

```
i=$a
while [ "$i" -le 3 ]
do
    echo -n $i
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```